# How to update a Collection without reloading the template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I created an event that saves a post each time the user inputs something (an tiny autosave system):

```
Template.postSubmit.events

  "keypress .simditor-body": function() {
    var post;
    post = {
        title: $("#input-title").val(),
        content: $("#input-content").val()
    };
    Posts.update(this._id, {
      $set: post
    });
    console.log("saved");
  }
```

[image]

(`#input-content` has the same content as `.simditor-body`)
The problem is that the template reloads each time the user types in `.simditor-body`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Previous to Meteor 0.8 there was `{{#constant}}`, `{{#isolate}}`, and `preserve`, but these are [now deprecated with blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#no-more-constant-isolate-or-preserve).

You can pass `reactive` as false in your query to tell meteor not to watch the collection for changes:
http://docs.meteor.com/#find

For example:

```
YourCollection.find( yourMongoSelector, {reactive:false});
```

Comment: Good question, the answer is no, there's no option to turn off reactivity in an update http://docs.meteor.com/#update.  This makes sense because there may be some other place where you want to have reactive updates.  Your page is reloading when you `update`, so there must be some reactive computation that's checking for changes on your Post collection.  I assumed that it was `find`, but it could be something else.